# Initialize connection to oracle db to reuse across lambda written in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-oracledb

I have a lambda function written in Node 6.10, that connects to oracle db. I am using oracledb module. Since the connection to the oracle db takes over 10 seconds, I would like to reuse the connection object across multiple executions of lambda.

worker.js

```
const os = require('os');
var fs = require('fs');
const str_host = os.hostname() + ' localhost\n';
var oracledb;
var connection;
var properties;

fs.appendFile(process.env.HOSTALIASES,str_host , function(err){
  if(err) throw err;    
});

try {
  if (typeof oracledb === 'undefined' || oracledb === null ) {
    oracledb = require('oracledb');
    console.log( 'Oracle DB is supported');
    if(typeof connection === 'undefined' || connection === null) {
      console.log("Getting a new connection");
      getDBConnection(properties, oracledb, function(err,conn) {
        if(err) {
          callback(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Setting connection object");
          connection = conn;
          callback();
        }
      });
    }
  }
} catch(dbError) {
  console.log('Failed to load oracledb:');
  console.log(dbError);
}

function getDBConnection(properties, oracledb, callback) {
  var dbProperties = {
    user          : properties[DB_USER],
    password      : properties[DB_PASSWORD],
    connectString : properties[DB_CONNECTION_STRING]
  };

  try {
    if (typeof oracledb !== 'undefined' && oracledb !== null ) {
        oracledb.getConnection(dbProperties)
         .then( conn => {
            console.log("After getting connection" + conn);                
             return callback(null, conn);
        })
        .catch(err => { 
            console.log("Error getting connection" + err);
            return callback(err, null);
        });
    } else {
        console.log("oracledb is undefined");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed to connect oracledb');
    console.log(e);
    return callback(e, null);
  }
}

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  console.log('Inside worker');
  console.log(context);

  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  work();
});
```

The execution of handler does not wait until connection from oracleDB is received. Also please note that in the getDbConnection method, the

oracledb.getConnection(options) returns a promise and I have a then and catch to make sure connection is resolved. but I still have the work method execute before connection object is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I did the following and it works and lambda reused the oracleDB connection for the subsequent calls as long as it can retain the context.

The change is moved the try catch block initializes the connection within the exports.handler the starting point of lamdba. And defined the connection variable as a global variable.

```
var connection;
var oracledb;

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
 console.log('Inside worker');
 console.log(context);

 context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
 try {
  if (typeof oracledb === 'undefined' || oracledb === null ) {
    oracledb = require('oracledb');
    console.log( 'Oracle DB is supported');
    if(typeof connection === 'undefined' || connection === null) {
      console.log("Getting a new connection");
      getDBConnection(properties, oracledb, function(err,conn) {
        if(err) {
          callback(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Setting connection object");
          connection = conn;
          callback();
         }
       });
     }
   }
 } catch(dbError) {
  console.log('Failed to load oracledb:');
  console.log(dbError);
 }
 work();
});
```

I am not completely happy with this implementation. Is there any other solution?